# Can a vectorized numpy function use a buffer as an output?

Tags: python, numpy

Can I get a numpy vectorized function to use a buffer object as the result as opposed to creating a new array that is returned by that object?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
fun = numpy.vectorize(lambda x: x + 1)
a = numpy.zeros((1, 10)
buf = numpy.zeros((1, 10)
fun(a, buf_obj = buf)
```

as opposed to

```
fun = numpy.vectorize(lambda x: x + 1)
a = numpy.zeros((1, 10)
buf = fun(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not for `vectorize`, but most numpy functions take an `out` argument that does exactly what you want.

What function are you trying to use `numpy.vectorize` with?  `vectorize` is almost always the wrong solution when you're trying to "vectorize" a calculation.

In your example above, if you wanted to do the operation in-place, you could accomplish it with:

```
a = numpy.zeros((1, 10))
a += 1
```

Or, if you wanted to be a bit verbose, but do exactly what your example would do:

```
a = numpy.zeros((1, 10))
buf = numpy.empty_like(a)
numpy.add(a, 1, out=buf)
```

`numpy.vectorize` has to call a python function for every element in the array.  Therefore, it has additional overhead when compared to numpy functions that operate on the entire array. Usually, when people refer to "vectorizing" an expression to get a speedup, they're referring to building the expression out of building-blocks of basic numpy functions, rather than using `vectorize` (which is certainly confusing...).

---

*Edit:* Based on your comment, `vectorize` really does fit your use case! (Writing a "raster calculator" is a pretty perfect use case for it, beyond security/sandboxing issues.)

On the other hand, [`numexpr`](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) is probably an even better fit if you don't mind an additional dependency.

It's faster and takes an `out` parameter.

Comment: I have an api that applies a user defined function across an array of 2D matrices.  The matrices can be larger than memory,  misaligned, and maybe even represent different cell sizes (this is a GIS problem).  I allow the user to pass in a function that will operate on an arbitrary stack of pixels after I've interpolated and aligned all the data.  Is there a better mechanism to allow users to operate on data like that?

Comment: Well, in that case, `vectorize` is probably what you want!  On the other hand, you might look into `numexpr` instead. For one thing, it's generally much faster and secondly, it takes an `out` parameter.